# Stop an in-progress query-string-authorized download on Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

With Amazon S3, can I stop a query-string-authorized download that is in progress?

Are there other file download services that provide such a feature?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a built in way to do this.  If I understand your goal, you want to potentially stop an HTTP response mid-stream based on some custom rules you have.  Is that right?

If so, perhaps you could write a very thin proxy to S3 that encapsulates this logic.  If you ran the proxy on EC2 you wouldn't incur any additional bandwidth fees.

The downside is that you would have manage scaling the proxy (i.e. add more EC2 nodes based on traffic) so depending on your scaling requirements, this could require a bit of work.  But the proxy script itself would probably be fairly trivial.  Something like:

```
Make streaming HTTP request to S3 for object
for each x byte chunk in response from S3:
    Check auth condition.  Continue if valid.  Break if not.
    Send chunk to caller
```

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting idea. It's cool that there wouldn't be additional bandwidth fees, but I would lose out on the distributed S3 architecture (sending files to a user from the closest data center).

Comment: Just a note to the above comment. S3 is certainly distributed but not in the sense you are referring to by "the closest data center". All data is stored within the same region you selected for your bucket. What you refer to would be CloudFront (their CDN service).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anyone that allows this. In general, the authentication is only checked once, when you begin downloading, but not thereafter.

Can you describe what you're trying to do more broadly?

Comment: After a user begins downloading a file, there are circumstances where I want to revoke their access to it and stop streaming the file to them while it is in the middle of being downloaded.